# Java Calendar set time to 12am of previous day in UTC

Tags: java, calendar, utc

Can someone explain why or if this code is wrong?

```
// main
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
```

It produces:

```
Fri Jan 28 15:27:35 EST 2011
Thu Jan 27 15:27:35 EST 2011
Wed Jan 26 19:27:35 EST 2011
```

Am I missing something obvious?  I expect to see something like Thu Jan 27 00:27:35 EST 2011

Thanks.

Comment: How is 00:27:35 the same as setting the time to 12am? I would expect 12 am to be 00:00:00.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're printing it out in the default time zone, not UTC. Although your *calendar* knows the time zone you're interested in, the `java.util.Date` returned by `getTime()` doesn't... and `Date.toString()` uses the system time zone.

Given that you *specified in the subject* that you wanted 12am in UTC, why would you expect to see Thu Jan 27 00:27:35 EST 2011? EST isn't the same as UTC.

EDIT: As always, I'd just like to point out that [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) is generally a *much* nicer API to use for date/time arithmetic in Java. You're currently getting the right answer, but I'd still recommend moving to Joda :)

Comment: good point.  so is the math actually accurate and my output is just wrong?

Answer (score 2):

EST is UTC - 5 hours, so 19:27 EST corresponds to 00:27 UTC. It seems logical to me.
Use a date format with a UTC locale to display your calendars, instead of using your default locale.

Answer (score 0):

For UTC calculations (only) you might find using long is simpler.

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
// yesterday at 12:00:00.000 am.
long yesterday = (time / 86400000 - 1) * 86400000;
```